# New session login script not working in PHP

Tags: php

I am using this script see below, which I got from this site to login users and redirect  to a webpage based on their login. It works great but I am having trouble pulling the username into the page they are redirected to. The new session script below usually works with simple scripts but it does not appear to work with this redirect script. If someone could point me in the right direction I would be grateful as I am very new to PHP, this is my first attempt. Thanks Alan

Redirect script works great.

```
<?php 
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="trydata"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB"); 
// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['username']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['password']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection) 
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername); 
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword); 
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername); 
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword); 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and   password='$mypassword'"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql); 


// Mysql_num_row is counting table row 
$count = mysql_num_rows($result); 

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row 
if($count == 1){ 
    // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file"login_success.php" 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername; 
    $_SESSION['password'] = $mypassword; 

    $result = mysql_fetch_array($result); // get the result set from the query

    $redirect = trim($result['redirect']); // get the redirect column's value

    if ($redirect == '') {
        echo "No redirect value was set!";
    } else {
        header('Location: ' . $redirect);
        exit;
    }
} else { 
    echo "Wrong Username or Password"; 
} 

?>

New session script not pulling loin information through.

<?php 
session_start(); // start up your PHP session! 


if (isset($_SESSION['username'])
{

    echo "You are logged in as ".$_SESSION['username'];
    echo "<p>";

    echo "<a href='logout.php'> Click here to logout<a/>";
    }

else

header ("Location: form.php");

?>
```

Comment: Use a different tutorial to learn PHP. The one you are using is horribly bad. `stripslashes` will break the string if it contains any backslashes and magic quotes are not enabled. (MQ are deprecated and a bad thing)

Comment: Thanks for responding, it appears to work with the advice below and I will get a better tutorial for PHP. Thanks again.Regards

Answer (score 0):

try using [session_write_close](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) just before redirecting:

```
if ($redirect == '') {
    echo "No redirect value was set!";
} else {
    session_write_close(); 
    header('Location: ' . $redirect);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question, now got it working with the advice above. Thanks again for your help. Regard

Comment: so feel free to upvote/accept this answer and upvote every other answer that has been useful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set session_start();  on the top line, after the `<?php` line of **both** your scripts which access the $_SESSION array.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start(); <----------------Session should start here 
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="trydata"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB"); 
// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['username']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['password']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection) 
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername); 
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword); 
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername); 
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword); 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and   password='$mypassword'"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql); 


// Mysql_num_row is counting table row 
$count = mysql_num_rows($result); 

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row 
if($count == 1){ 
    // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file"login_success.php" 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername; 
    $_SESSION['password'] = $mypassword; 

    $result = mysql_fetch_array($result); // get the result set from the query

    $redirect = trim($result['redirect']); // get the redirect column's value

    if ($redirect == '') {
        echo "No redirect value was set!";
    } else {
        header('Location: ' . $redirect);
        exit;
    }
} else { 
    echo "Wrong Username or Password"; 
} 

?>

New session script not pulling loin information through.

<?php 



if (isset($_SESSION['username'])
{

    echo "You are logged in as ".$_SESSION['username'];
    echo "<p>";

    echo "<a href='logout.php'> Click here to logout<a/>";
    }

else

header ("Location: form.php");

?>
```

You need to call `session_start()` at the very beginning.

and I advice you to learn [PDO](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Prepared-Statement-P550.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help, it now works perfectly and I will lean PDO as you suggested. Thanks again much appreciated.